# How to LINQ to filter custom Object?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I am using following class and in my C# code I am doing DB call which will get data from SQL table and convert that into `ObjParent = List<Parent>`

```
class Parent
{
 string a;
 string b;
 int c;
 MyEnum d;
 List<Sub> e;
}

class Sub
{
 String f;
 int g;
 bool h;
}
```

Now my Input is `ObjParent = List< Parent>` in c#, and my requirement is to filter this object with where criteria as `(Boolean) h= True/ False` and in return type it should be again provide a filtered list `objFilteredParent = List< Parent>`

As filter is for Sub List hence I am stuck here, on how to get it done through LINQ

Comment: each `Parent` has a list of `Sub`, so your `criteria` doesn't make sense to filter your list of `Parent`.

Comment: A concrete example would be helpful, including the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify if **all** `Sub` elements have to met the condition, on only **one** of them, but you should use either **`All`** or **`Any`** method:

```
var objFilteredParent = ObjParent.Where(x => x.e.All(y => y.h)).ToList();

// or

var objFilteredParent = ObjParent.Where(x => x.e.Any(y => y.h)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hemant sir,
As per your question it was not clear, you needed all the objects in the `List<Sub>` to have `true` value of `h` or just any one of them is `true`.
If you want all the values to have `true` use this,

```
 List<Parent> objFilteredParent = ObjParent.FindAll(par => par.e.All(sub => sub.h));
```

and if you need that any one in list is having `true` value use,

```
 List<Parent> objFilteredParent = ObjParent.FindAll(par => par.e.Any(sub => sub.h));
```

One more thing I noticed while pasting the contents, that `List<Sub>` and `bool h` was `private` make it `public` or add some properties for both the variables and then replace those variables name with there corresponding property name in above LINQ.
For example, I have made those variables `public`

```
    class Parent
    {
        string a;
        string b;
        int c;
        //MyEnum d;
        public List<Sub> e;
    }

    class Sub
    {
        String f;
        int g;
        public bool h;
    }
```